# How to solve the equation $(f \circ f)(x)=x$?

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

Solve the equation $(f \circ f)(x)=x$, if $f(x) = \frac {2x+1}{x+2}$ and $x \in \mathbb R$ \ $\{-2\}$.

How would I solve this equation and what does it even mean to be solved in this context?

Comment: It means find all values $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $(f\circ f)(x)=x$. You solve it by computing $f\circ f$ first.

Comment: @Levent How could I solve it? Can you show it to me?

Comment: @MathBear Looks like homework...

Comment: Maybe to make computations easier: consider the isomorphism between linear fractional transforms and $GL(2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $(f\circ f)(x)=x$, then
$$\frac{2f(x)+1}{f(x)+2}=x$$
$$\frac{2\frac{2x+1}{x+2}+1}{\frac{2x+1}{x+2}+2}=x$$
And after you solve it (it should turn into a quadratic), don't forget to cut out the extraneous solutions!

Comment: So $ \frac {6x+6}{4x+5} = x \\ \frac {6x+6}{4x+5} - x = 0 \\ \frac {6x+6-4x^2-5x}{4x+5} = 0 |\cdot(4x+5) \text { for } x \neq 1.25 \\ 6x+6-4x^2-5x=0 \\ -4x^2 +x +6 = 0 \\ \text {Is that correct?}$

Comment: Nope. At the beginning, you should have had
$$\frac{5x+4}{4x+5}=x$$

Comment: Right, but shouldn't it be $\frac {5x+4}{4x+5} = x$ at the beginning?

Comment: @MathBear Right, sorry. Looks like we both have fallible algebra. XD

Comment: So $ \frac {5x+4}{4x+5} = x \\ \frac {5x+4}{4x+5} - x = 0 \\ \frac {5x+4-4x^2-5x}{4x+5} = 0 |\cdot(4x+5) \text { for } x \neq 1.25 \\ -4x^2+4=0 \\ -4x^2 = -4 |\cdot(-\frac{1}{4}) \\ x^2 = 1 \\ x = |1| \\ x_1 = 1 \text { and } x_2 = -1 \\ \text {Is that correct for the final answer?}$

Answer (score 1):

Solve $\dfrac{2\left(\dfrac{2x+1}{x+2}\right)+1}{\dfrac{2x+1}{x+2}+2}=x$ for $x\ne-2$.

Answer (score 0):

**How to begin:**
$$f\bigl(f(x)\bigr)=\frac{2f(x)+1}{f(x)+2}=\frac{2\cfrac{2x+1}{x+2}+1}{\cfrac{2x+1}{x+2}+2}=\cdots$$